# Tengo un problemas con la librería plyer de python, la función gps no me muestra la longitud ni latitud

Tags: python

> Tengo problemas con este código, es una app para el celular, que no logro que me muestre los valores de la longitud ni latitud. Doy los permisos android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION en el archivo buildozer y nada. También le doy permiso a la app para que puede usar la ubicación del celular.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from plyer import gps

class GPSApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        self.latitude_label = Label(text="Latitud: ")
        self.longitude_label = Label(text="Longitud: ")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.latitude_label)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.longitude_label)

        # Iniciamos la actualización de la ubicación
        gps.configure(on_location=self.on_location, on_status=self.on_status)
        gps.start()

        # Actualizamos la ubicación cada segundo
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_location, 10)
        return self.layout

    def on_location(self, **kwargs):
        self.latitude_label.text = "Latitud: {}".format(kwargs['lat'])
        self.longitude_label.text = "Longitud: {}".format(kwargs['lon'])

    def on_status(self, stype, status):
        if stype == 'error':
            print('GPSp error: ', status)

    def update_location(self, dt):
        gps.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GPSApp().run()
```

Comment: intentaste en otro equipo???

Comment: que error te da el log del IDE???

Comment: si probé en dos equipos y no me muestra nada. 

Lo probé directamente en el celular y es como que la función on_location nunca es llamada para que me muestre los valores

Comment: A mí me pasa igual. Lo he probado en dos dispositivos, he hecho los mismos ajustes que has hecho, y nada.